# Handing multiple simultaneous requests using epoll

Tags: c++, linux, server, epoll

I'm attempting to learn how to use epoll for the purpose creating a server that takes and executes commands from a client (login, download file, etc).  So far I've gotten the program to simply send the client all data it recieves, but I noticed that when I tried to implement the commands I listed, the server would only handle one request at a time.

I'm trying to come up with an efficient way I can handle many commands at the same time.  So far the only idea I've come up with is to create a separate thread to handle each request, but I'm not sure if that's an optimal solution.  What would be a good way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your architecture is epoll + single thread, then it will has some blocking issue if your command is heavy load. That's why redis's performance will drop down when certain command is blocking.

There are other architectures that possible. But before you try those, do some performance testing first. If redis could do millions OPS within single thread, you could do that as well.

epoll + command per thread: just as you said. But thread creation and destruction will add the cost when load is going up. Frequently context switch is also a huge problem.

epoll + thread pool: Sample idea. But without the drawbacks above.

epoll based listener + N*(epoll worker): this is interesting structure. The epoll listener will get request from the user, but instead of directly assigned the job to a thread, it register the file descriptor to the epoll of one following worker. In this way, the listener thread is freed and could accept connections faster.

Comment: I'm not sure what "redis" is, but it sounds interesting.  Also, I really like the epoll + thread idea.  How do you think that would compare performance-wise to command per thread?

Comment: Another small question, is there any general rule of how many threads I should place into the thread pool if I went for a epoll + thread pool design?

Comment: redis is more or less the most popular in-memory datastore in this industry. you mean the epoll+threadpool? That would be better than epoll+(command per thread), in theory. Performance testing is a big topic. I doubt you can see the difference given small testing set.

Comment: Well, no general rule I guess. In production, we have tool to profile the program and get the context-switch-number and tune the program based on that.

Comment: I would suggest one more architecture (as an extension of listener + N*workers): epoll listener + message queue + pool of workers. But this would be beneficial if you plan to scale your app for a very heavy load - message queue will allow you to distribute work among other processes or computing nodes in cluster.

Comment: @iwlagn Could you elaborate on that or provide examples/articles/books I could look at to get a better idea of how to design a system that would do that?

Comment: Basic idea is very simple: you introduce intermediate storage for your incoming messages for which epoll listener acts as a producer. Pool of workers somehow (shared memory, socket etc) connected to this message queue and first available worker grabs a message from the top of the queue and starts processing, then comes second second worker and so on. You can use distributed message queues, which will allow you to add new workers just by connecting new servers to your cluster. You can have a look on AMQP (http://www.amqp.org) and it's implementations to get an idea of distributed messaging.

Comment: And here http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/papers/mdw-phdthesis.pdf you can find PhD thesis describing complex architecture for concurrent services, that utilizes messaging queues.

Comment: Wow, that concept is very interesting.  Thanks for helping me understand that solution.